# Android Set ListView OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

Here's my Activity opening.

```
public class SettingActivityR extends CommBaseActivity implements OnItemClickListener
```

the CommBaseActivity is a class handle communication that extends from Activity

and the Structure in SettingActivityR contains a listView names SeverListView

I had set these settings in Activity onCreate Method

```
    SeverlistView.setAdapter(this.m_adapter);  
    SeverlistView.setClickable(true);//already set it Clickable!
    SeverlistView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

and override the Method

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
SeverDataList targetSeverItem=m_adapter.items.get(arg2);
Log.i("bird","zzz");    
}
```

The Adapter works fine,but the OnItemClickListener didn't work at all. The debug mode don't even run into this method. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SettingActivityR should extend ListActivity instead.

In the onCreate(), call setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);

From here, the onListItemClick() method should handle the callback for you.

Comment: but SettingActivityR is not just a ListView,

If I still need SettingActivityR extended from Activity

How can I do?

Comment: Unless your Activity requires more than 1 ListView to be displayed, otherwise a ListActivity is pretty self sufficient, you can still add and customize other widgets as per normal.

Comment: hum....but I still want to use the structure in Activity...

cause every Activity can extend from it...

Comment: I have a code which is the structure just like what I want...
(Activity contains a ListView and work fine)
But i just can't find where's different with mine...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing your `Adapter` with the sample provided [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)? Scroll to the end of the page and you will see

```
String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries));
```

If this works fine but your adapter doesn't, then there could be something specific you need to do in your adapter. Could you share your adapter code as well?

Comment: We need to see more code to be able to help you. I created a simple `Activity` (not a `ListActivity`)  and tried out the example in the link I provided above. It worked fine. I could see the `Toast`.